# Console logs not showing request and response json

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm successfully running a server inside of VSCode but the request and response logs that I'm used to seeing in my terminal when I run my server with `npm start` aren't showing up. Would love for them to show in the Debug Terminal somehow.

my `launch.json`:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Dev",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/index.js",
        "env": {
            "PORT": "1337",
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: where is the console logging code?  If your logging from Node it will show up in the terminal, if your logging from node it will not show up in the console of your web browser.   Can you share your logging code?

Comment: I'm just doing simple `console.log(someVar)` throughout my code. This is a server that my mobile app connects to, so I'm not running a chrome tab or anything

Comment: So if it's in your node code, it should log to the console/cmd/terminal just fine. https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/stdio.html . We probably need to see the code.

Comment: As Chris Hawkes has mentioned, check the terminal where you started node.

Comment: Looks like my issue was I'm used to seeing the request and response logs which auto-show when I run `npm start` in my terminal but aren't showing in my VSCode terminal, that's actually what I'm trying to achieve, will update my question now

Answer (score 1):

Only code that runs from your server side node.js code will display console.log data in the window in VSCode, all client side console.log will show in your developer tools on whatever browser your running.